# Query with paramaters MySQL & C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Hey I'm trying to output to a label when I try to add parameters to my mySql query
it works fine if I manually set the parameters to "admin"  using this sql statement "string sql = "SELECT login_Type FROM schooladmindb.login WHERE Password ='admin'AND Email ='admin'";" but when  what to input the variables i get no output

```
      string password = Txtpassword.ToString();
      string email = Txtpassword.ToString();
     string sql = "SELECT login_Type FROM schooladmindb.login WHERE Password = @password AND Email = @email";

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("");
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);


    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
          string type = reader.GetString(1);
          Lbltest.Text = type; 


        //data2txtz.Text = reader.GetString("id");
        //datatxt.Text = reader.GetString("userId");
    }
```

I'm getting no output when I enter admin into both text boxes, I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: Missing connection string? or did you just remove it for your posting here.

Comment: `string email = Txtpassword.ToString();` doesn't sound like it's right to me. And if `Txtpassword` is a textbox, you want the `Text` property, not calling `ToString`...

Comment: (Of course, if you're really storing passwords in plaintext, you've got *huge* security problems to start with...)

Comment: Yup that was my problem thanks, as for the passwords nothing to worry about its on my to do list, for now this is just me messing around on asp.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the second column in the results:

```
reader.GetString(1)
```

But only selecting one column:

```
SELECT login_Type FROM schooladmindb.login
```

Get the first column instead:

```
reader.GetString(0)
```

---

Also, what is `Txtpassword`?  You're calling `.ToString()` on it, but is it come kind of input like a `TextBox`?  I can't know this *for certain* based on the code shown, but you *might* be using the wrong value here.  You'll have to debug to find out.

But the point is that if `Txtpassword` is a `TextBox` or other similar control, you probably want its `.Text` property.  `.ToString()` would just give you the name of the class.

---

Additionally, do you notice that you're using the same user input for both the password *and* the email?  That may be a typo on your part.  Again, I can't know for certain.  But it's worth checking on your end.

---

You also have a typo here:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.);
//                                 right here ---^
```

Which is preventing your code from compiling *at all*.  So... You might want to take a look at the error messages that the compiler is giving you.

---

Side note, but an **important** one: Storing user passwords in plain text is a *famouly **bad idea***.  And it's grossly irresponsible to the users.  User passwords should be obscured with a 1-way hash and should *never* be readable in their original form.  Not even by you as the system owner.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was the to.String() and the reader.GetString(1) that was my problem thanks for the help! as for the passwords its nothing live, its for me and i will be trying to store them properly once ihave functionality